# 13.10: Partial upgrade created held broken packages

Tags: 13.10, apt, wine, package-management

After the last upgrade yesterday some weird things happened. The update uninstalled netflix-desktop, wine and PlayOnLinux and I have not being able to install them again from the terminal nor the Software Center or aptitude. I've dived into each forum and debian guide but the problem is still there. In one of those "autoremove" and "autoclean", even the unity desktop was uninstalled and had to install it again. These are the things I've tried, and didn't work at all:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo dpkg --configure -a
...
```

All of the above didn't fix the problem. When I run the command to see the packages on "hold", nothing comes up. I'm suspecting that there is something very "broken" with the wine dependencies, as when I use Synaptics, it give me also an error message and shows no unmet dependencies. Here is the error:

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I've also tried to install one by one the dependencies, but I get errors and once I saw a loop (deadlock).

Now, here are my questions:

- Is there a way to fix this without reinstalling Ubuntu?
- How can I manually purge or clean any mixed solitary wine installation?
- Is there a way to refresh Ubuntu to a clean install to clear the dependancy tree?

I'm suspecting that some dependency might be "dirty" between versions (netflix-desktop uses 1.5, I've tried to install 1.6, 1.7, and 1.4)

Comment: post the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: You do realize he tried that, right?

Comment: from the output of `sudo apt-get install -f` command, we can be able to figure out this problem.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Ah, output. My bad. On an unrelated node, netflix-desktop doesn't seem to have any external dependencies (besides dpkg), so I'm not sure why the upgrade uninstalled that package and wine. I do know that PPAs are disabled during upgrade.